# When loading data using THREE.js and pushing the result to a list, the list remains empty

Tags: javascript, three.js

I run data using the following function :

```
function loadData(){
    const loader = THREE.FileLoader();
    let loadedData = [];
    loader.load( dataFileUrl,
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (let row of data.split('\n'))
            {
                loadedData.push(row);
            }
        },
        function (xhr) {console.log( ('Loading data : ' + xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' )},
        function(err)  {console.error(err)}
    );
    return loadedData;
}
```

Here, `dataFileUrl` is the correct hashed url of the file  I intend to load (and the file is just a csv with some strings for each row in it).
I know the file is loaded correctly as I can log the content of it, but this whole method returns an empty list.
I'm rather new to js, I don't get why this wouldn't work the way I intend it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loading is asynchronous, you should return a promise

```js
function loadData(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let loadedData = [];
        loader.load(dataFileUrl,
            function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (let row of data.split('\n')) {
                    loadedData.push(row);
                }
                resolve(loadedData)
            },
            function (xhr) { console.log(('Loading data : ' + xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded') },
            function (err) { console.error(err) }
        );
    })
}
```

something like this should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I still have something I don't understand though.

Then, If I make a promise like this : 
`let loaderData = [];`
`let p = new Promise((r) => loader.load (...));`
`p.then(console.log(loadedData));`
I will still log an empty list. I don't get how synchronicity is affecting my code ?

Comment: try `.then(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: Ok, the issue doesn't directly come from my loader or has anything to do with three, I think it's simple js syntax I don't understand well. I narrowed down the issue to another question :

This code below logs an empty array : 
`const x = []; let c = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(()=>{x.push(4);})); c.then((r) => console.log(x));`

I don't get why it doesn't log an array filled with a single int equals to 4 ?

Comment: `.then(e => console.log(e))` doesn't log anything. I think we could expect that as the function inside the Promise doesn't return anything.

Comment: resolving the promise is giving me the result I expect. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thank you very much also for the extra clarifications :)

Comment: glad to be of help